# Condense multiple lines of var = false code to less lines?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have ten buttons. When one is clicked I want the corresponding div to fade in and when another button is clicked I want the div to fade out and the new div to fade in.

My method is not working correctly because my knowledge of JS is limited. I am currently running with something like this:

```
var active01 = false;
var active02 = false;
var active03 = false;
var active04 = false;
var active05 = false;

$("#button1").click(function () {
    active02 = false;
    active03 = false;
    active04 = false;
    active05 = false;
    active01 = true;
});

if(active01){
//fadein;
} else{
//fadeout;
}
```

Is there a way to set all the active buttons to false without having to write everything out each time? Something like this....

```
var active01 = false;
var active02 = false;
var active03 = false;
var active04 = false;
var active05 = false;
var actives = active01, active02, active03, active04, active05;

$("#button1").click(function () {
    actives = false;
    active01 = true;
});
```

Comment: you're doing sth wrong. use an array

Comment: addy2012 I am doing what wrong? and use an array for the second bit you mean?

Comment: Don't use 5 variables, but an array. Then you can also easily loop over it to set each value to `false`. And then just do sth like`actives[index] = true`.

Comment: It has been awhile since I have learned about arrays so I will need to some more research before it makes sense. thanks for pointing me in the right direction!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an array

```
var active = [];
for(i = 0; i<10; i++){
    active.push(false);
}
$("#button1").click(function () {
    for(i = 0; i<active.length; i++){
        active[i] = false;
    }
    active[1] = true;
});
```

Comment: Why not an actual array `[]`?

Answer (score 3):

Optionally you could use data elements to help you out.  For instance...

```
<input type="button" data-key="1">
<input type="button" data-key="2">
<div data-key="1"></div>
<div data-key="2"></div>
```

Given this setup you could have event handlers on the inputs.  When on is clicked, fade all your divs.  Then find the div that corresponds to your input with `$('div').filter('[data-key="'+ $(this).data('key') +'"]')` and then you can perform your fade in logic on it.

Comment: Changed .find() to .filter() which is the correct usage.

Comment: Also, if you're supporting newer browsers, you can just store a list of references to the actual divs. From there, you can add and remove CSS classes to the divs and not even track the state at all. Fade-in and Fade-out could just be CSS transitions, where available, which should be more efficient anyway. IE9 would jump between opaque and transparent, but IE10+ and basically everything else would be optimal animations.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use it like this

```js
$('.fade-target-container').on('click', function() {
  var targetContainer = $(this).attr('data-target');

  $('.fadeable-div').hide('fast');
  $('#' + targetContainer).show('fast');
});
```

```css
.fadeable-div {
 display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="fade-target-container" data-target="div1">My Button 01</button>
<button class="fade-target-container" data-target="div2">My Button 02</button>
<button class="fade-target-container" data-target="div3">My Button 03</button>
<button class="fade-target-container" data-target="div4">My Button 04</button>
<button class="fade-target-container" data-target="div5">My Button 05</button>

<div class="fadeable-div" id="div1">DIV1</div>
<div class="fadeable-div" id="div2">DIV2</div>
<div class="fadeable-div" id="div3">DIV3</div>
<div class="fadeable-div" id="div4">DIV4</div>
<div class="fadeable-div" id="div5">DIV5</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give an exact answer without seeing the HTML, but I can give it to you in pseudocode and we can go from there.

You don't need variables to do this . . . from what you've stated, you want all the `div`s to be hidden, unless their associated button is clicked, and then, only that one `div` should show.  You can do this with jQuery selectors pretty easily.

```
$(".commonButtonClass").on("click", function() {
    $(".commonDivClass").fadeOut();
    $("...SELECTOR_TO_FIND_THE_ASSOCIATED_DIV...").fadeIn();
});
```

Each `div` would need to have the `commonDivClass` class assigned to them and the buttons need to have the `commonButtonClass` assigned to them.  then, based on whatever relationship ties the buttons to their specific `div`s, you would need to create the correct selector to replace "...SELECTOR_TO_FIND_THE_ASSOCIATED_DIV...".

Using this, you don't need to track the states of the `div`s, just make sure that they are all hidden, before you show the one that is paired with the button that was clicked.

(P.S. - If you provide the actual HTML, I can give you a more exact answer, but, hopefully, you can figure it out from what I've posted.)